# Bigquery and Google Data Studio - 1 min refresh

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a google data studio dashboard where I switched data source from Google Sheets to BigQuery as BigQuery provided option of 1 minute data refresh. But when I started using BigQuery the data refresh speed was even slower than sheets - The sheets data got updated automatically after 15 mins but BigQuery data didnt get updated even after an hours.

I have set data refresh interval to 1 min for BigQuery data source but that does not appear to be working. I suspect this could be something related to data caching by BigQuery BI engine but I dont see an option to disable that.

Any pointers on above issue and how can I achieve every minute update with GDS and bigquery?

TIA
dbeings

Answer (score 0):

You Can schedule your query in Bigquery Studio for your desired intervals and also use the Bigquery BI engine to reduce your costs.

Comment: Thanks but I have already setup refresh interval in Google data studio. Isnt that supposed to work. I dont have a separate query in BigQuery that I am executing. I just setup my dimensions and metrics in Google Data Studio. Setup in GDS here: https://i.ibb.co/55PJxw2/data-freshness.jpg

Comment: The data freshness check only ensures the connection with source updating interval. To update your table, you need to create a scheduled query or click refresh data in looker studio every time you use your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, just one more clarification - the underlying bigquery table is getting updated every 5 mins as expected. When you say "You Can schedule your query in Bigquery Studio" does that mean some approach in which BigQuery pushes data to GDS and GDS table updates. If its a different table in BigQuery, then I am anyways getting the data updated there

Comment: Right, scheduled queries make your data updated and data freshness check the source for the latest data. also, you can use a materialized table to reduce scheduled query costs.